# How are Linux user/group quotas counted if a file is owned by both the user and the group?

Tags: linux, users, group, quota

I want to set up a `/home` where users have their own private folder and in addition share a different group folder with other users.
The goal is that users have their own small-sized folder for private files and the bulk of data is shared in the group folder

Let's say user quotas are set at 100GB and group quota at 1TB. We have a group 'G' consisting of users 'A', 'B' and 'C'

I wonder what happens if user A makes a file in the group G folder. For clarity the file permission in this example are userA:groupG.

For these files are they added to the user quota, the group quota or both?
And if they are counted to both quotas how can I change it so that files created at the group level are not added to the user quota?

I think I address a very basic point but I haven't found an answer to it online. Sorry if I missed it somehow.
Any explanations will be gladly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that a file created by user:A in group:G will count to both quotas. That is, the file is owned by user:A, so it counts towards their quota and the file is in group:G so it counts towards the group quota.

How can you stop this happening? Given that (in RedHat at least) the quota is assigned by file system, the only way to have *only* group quotas on the group area is to make it a separate file system. And in fact if the shared area has only one group sharing it, you could limit that by only allocating enough space instead of having a group quota.

So you'd want /dev/vg1/lv1 mounted as /home and /dev/vg1/lv2 mounted as /home/shared and then put user quotas on /dev/vg1/lv1 ... and either put group quotas on /dev/vg1/lv2 or just create /dev/vg1/lv2 of a size that is right for the only group quota.

I'm sure you've looked at all of the man pages and documentation for quota... but in case, this is the RedHat page that explains quotas... https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-disk-quotas.html